# In Dart, what's the history on the bare minimalism of the Type class?

Tags: dart

I'm a seasoned developer but a novice Dart learner.

To check a subtype of an instance without hardcoding the type name, I found you need a boilerplate  using the mirror library, like the following example.

```
import 'dart:mirrors';

class X {
}

class Y extends X {
}

void main() {
  final y = Y();
  final xType = X;
  //print(y is xType); // This raises an error, "'xType' isn't a type.".
  print(reflectType(y.runtimeType).isSubtypeOf(reflectType(xType)));
}
```

I found the `Type` class provides only bare minimal features. I guess it's a design decision of the core type system. What's the history on this?

The API reference on the `TypeMirror.isSubtypeOf()` says 'This is the type relationship used in `is` test checks.'. Does it imply that calling `reflectType()` two times and `isSubtypeOf()` one time introduces no critical performance overhead?

Comment: I've heard dart:mirrors is already broken, and there are no further plans to revive it.

Comment: The `Type` object has one job: To be a token that can be used with `dart:mirrors`.
It's also being used for other things, but since the only thing it promises is the behavior of `==` (even the `toString` behavior is not specified), all you *can* do is to compare it for equality. Which is less useful for generic types.
In practice, you shouldn't use `Type` objects for anything. (For experts: *Really* don't use `Type` objects!)